# Any alternatives to Google Trends?

Tags: statistics, search-engine, keyword

I'm writing a small helper utility for obscure software that is used at a local shop. **Basically, I would like to know if *anyone* searches for *anything* associated with that software and if publishing my work on the Internet would make any sense.** I entered the name of the software into Google Trends, but my terms "do not have enough search volume to show graphs" despite the fact that Google lists 250,000 results for the software name, or 35,000 if I explicitly remove terms such as serial and warez from the search.

Does anyone know of alternatives to Google Trends? Or of another way to find out if people search for a particular keyword?

Comment: You should ask about "obscure software" that involves search terms as "warez" on forums of people that deal with obscure and warez software. As for Google Trends it is still a Lab project.

Comment: @Krugar: Re-read the question carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found what I was looking for.
[Google AdWords Keyword Tool](https://adwords.google.com/select/KeywordToolExternal)

Comment: Except this service doesn't seem to show trends, unless I'm missing something, which is what I want to see.

Comment: Using the AdWords create a new campaign workflow, you can add keywords and see the search "trends" helpful to compare with google webmaster tools on your search traffic.

Answer (score 2):

[Yahoo Clues](http://clues.yahoo.com) is a service similar to Google Trends. But I don't think it's as effective for any category that is non-entertainment.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get an answer here, another place to ask might be [The Business of Software](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/?biz).

Comment: I actually found a tool that suited me better and I posted it as an answer. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1):

Google Trends was also telling me there wasn't enough data for my query. I found [Google Insights](http://www.google.com/insights/search/#) to do job nicely. And unlike the AdWords tool mentioned in the author's answer, it actually shows a trend.

Here's an [example](http://bit.ly/mGBpCu) which shows the emergence of 3 terms with too low of volume to show up on Trends: #bigdata, #datascientist & #datajournalism.

Here's a [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621156/google-search-trends).