# google search trends

Tags: search-engine

we can get google's hot trends based on location. is it possible to extract search trends on google based on specific terms say iphone. we search history of terms related to iphone.

is this facility provided by google or any other search engine.

Edit: is it possible to get data on search history categorized by topic?

Comment: Questions normally end with a question mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found my answer
[google insight](http://www.google.com/insights/search)
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

http://www.google.com/trends

Comment: but it won't tell me related terms

Comment: do you mean comparing of terms?

Comment: it is specific for the search term and not all searches that contained that term.