# Is it possible to find out how many times (and from where) a certain search query was made on Google?

Tags: search, search-engine

For example, if I am interested in finding out how many times in the past week "John Smith" was typed in Google/Yahoo/Bing/etc as a search query and where that query was made from (general location)?

Comment: http://www.google.com/trends/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not software-development specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via [google trends](http://www.google.com/trends) for example.

It shows the total amount of searches, and the relative popularity per location.
It won't show which day the searches came from which location.

Comment: I tried to search something and I get "Not enough search volume to show graphs". Any idea what is the minimum volume requirement for a query to be considered to be shown?

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul No idea, but you may want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412478/any-alternatives-to-google-trends).